# Django: How to add a manytomany field(from user to user itself) to the built in user model

Tags: django, many-to-many

example field that i want to add in built in User model

```
class bulit_in_user_model(models.Model):
    
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about referencing self using [**`ManyToManyField.symmetrical`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) here

```
from django.db import models

class MyUser(models.Model):
    ...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

Monkey patching could achieve your goal,but it's better to follow the normal **[`User model Customization`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)** though

Inherit from `AbstractUser`, and specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser` in your settings.

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

Comment: but am asking how to add this relationship to the built-in user model. her you have created another table MyUser. I am asking if I can add this field to built-in user Model?

Comment: @MihirJain Is there any reason that you don't follow the normal `User model customization`?

Comment: i got my answer, previously you didnt add the later part you just wrote the above code.

Comment: As i am in a midlle of the project so editing this and then running migrations would work fine? or I have to restart all the things from beginning.

Comment: @MihirJain Hi, it's quite complicated if you didn't start a project with a customized `User`, since `ContentType`, `Permissions` are automatically generated based on your old `User` model. You could follow the steps here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313, but I highly recommended to restart, it won't cost too much time